# How to set multiple folders for a server in VSCode SSH TARGETS?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

How to set multiple folders for a server in SSH TARGETS of VSCode Remote Explorer ?

```
SSH TARGETS
  10.0.1.123
    MyWebSite1 /var/www
```

I need to add MyWebSite2:

```
SSH TARGETS
  10.0.1.123
    MyWebSite1 /var/www
    MyWebSite2 /var/www
```

Comment: A related question is how to open multiple folders of remote (ssh) and local in the same workspace. Well that is not planned to be supported: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/706

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have connect to the same host again (ex:10.0.1.123) and once logged in, select a folder to open Ex: `/home/project1/src` or `/root/myapp/code`. Every "entry point" folder you select for that host, will be listing in the explorer. More details [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_remember-hosts-and-advanced-settings)

1. Right Click on Host or click the `Add` button
2. Connect SSH target (either New window or same)
3. Provide the path of the folder or choose `File > Open Folder`

[image: SSH connections with multiple entrypoints]

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it's `File > Open...` now

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2023:**

Easy solution: `File > Add Folder to Workspace`.

[image]